# use two repeat background image in a single div

Tags: html, css

I try to use two repeat background image in x direction for my div.But i can't.How can i use two repeat image in X direction in my div(i.e,i need to divide my singe div into two equal parts.For my first part i need to use my first image with background repeat-x and then rest part should be fill with my second image in repeat-x direction).Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your code can't really know what your going for but I would do this:

```
<div class="outer_div">
    <div class="left_half"></div>
    <div class="right_half"></div>
</div>

<style>
.outer_div{
    width: 500px; /*or whatever you need the width to be */
}
.left_half{
    background-image: url("your image here") repeat-x;
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
}
.right_half{
    background-image:url("your image here") repeat-x;
    width: 50%;
    float:right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `CSS3` for ***multiple*** backgrounds for a ***single*** `div`.

HTML:

```
<div class="backgrounds"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.backgrounds {
  background: url(http://userlogos.org/files/logos/pek/stackoverflow2.png),
              url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/3807b3e7ad69d363d4490540c663af5f?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  background-position: center, left;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle DEMO: Multiple Background For Single Div**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rgmxs/1/)

**EDIT:** Revised jsFiddle for `repeat-x` Read more about ***CSS3 multiple-backgrounds*** [**HERE**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds).